# Pushed an array into an array, got a string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

**Edit2**: Had problem ng-repeating an array because it was an array pushed into an array, so I was suggested to use concat() instead of push() and now it seems to work, but now the problem is that ng-repeat stopped entirely to work, it isn't repeating at all.

controller

```
$scope.table = new Array();
$scope.gallery = new Array();
$scope.add = function(inserzione) {
  $scope.table = [];
  $scope.table.push(inserzione);
  $scope.gallery = $scope.gallery.concat(inserzione.galleria);
  $location.path('dettagli');
  $timeout((function() {
     $window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }), 300);
};

$scope.remove = function(inserzione) {
  $scope.table = [];
  $scope.gallery = [];
  $location.path('/');
  $timeout((function() {
    $window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }), 300);
};
```

page

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12" ng-repeat="immagine in gallery"><img class="img-responsive center-block" ng-src="{{immagine}}"/></div>
</div>
```

plnkr

---

**Edit**: [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/QTu5haz9GrP6oSANYXNR?p=preview)

---

So.. I think a need some explanations at this point.

I have a function where some data from an array are pushed into another array, but no matter how do I manipulate them (toString/replace/split/arrayFrom madness) I always get a string.

expected: ["img1","img2"]

actually: [["img1","img2"]]

controller.js

```
(function() {
  (function() {
    var AggregateController;
    AggregateController = function($http, $scope, $window, $timeout) {
      var vm;
      vm = this;
      vm.inserzioni = new Array();
      $http.get("inserzioni.json").success(function(data) {
        vm.inserzioni = data;
      });
      $scope.table = new Array();
      $scope.gallery = new Array();
      $scope.add = function(inserzione) {
        $scope.table = [];
        $scope.table.push(inserzione);
        $scope.gallery.push(inserzione.galleria.toString().replace(/\["\]/g, '').split(','));
        $scope.gallery = Array.from($scope.gallery);
        $location.path('dettagli');
        $timeout((function() {
          $window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }), 300);
      };
      $scope.remove = function(inserzione) {
        var index;
        index = $scope.table.indexOf(inserzione);
        $scope.table.splice(index, 1);
        $location.path('/');
        $timeout((function() {
          $window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }), 300);
      };
    };
    AggregateController.$inject = ['$http', '$scope', '$window', '$timeout'];
    angular.module('realEstate').controller('AggregateController', AggregateController);
  })();

}).call(this);
```

inserzioni.json

```
[
  {
    "data": "08/10/2016",
    "titolo": "CSCIV100",
    "localita": "Centro Storico",
    "tipologia": "Casa indipendente",
    "contratto": "Vendita",
    "camere": 3,
    "bagni": 2,
    "prezzo": 100000,
    "fascia": "40-100",
    "copertina": "./img/CSCIV100.jpg",
    "galleria": [
      "./img/CSCIV100.jpg",
      "./img/CSCIV100.jpg"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal example? It seems to me that not all of this angular module is important to the problem you're having.

Comment: The value you're showing in actually is not a string, but an array of arrays. If you want to merge two arrays, look at [`Array.prototype.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

Comment: @domyos [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/QTu5haz9GrP6oSANYXNR?p=preview)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan now I have `$scope.gallery = $scope.gallery.concat(inserzione.galleria);` but ng-repeat is still not working

Comment: Since you haven't shared a [mcve] in the question itself, it's going to be guesswork.

Comment: What? There's a plnkr

Comment: **in the question itself** not on a third party site.

Comment: "but ng-repeat is still not working " first time you mention that. What do you get and what you expect? @EmanueleTuttolani

Comment: Uhm internet gone down another time, can't update my question.. @taguenizy well because at first it was "working" repeating just a single string, but now with concat() isn't repeating nothing at all. I'm expecting that it iterates through $scope.gallery but it isn't, and it isn't empty because using {{gallery}} it's there

Comment: check your console. I'm guessing you have duplicate data. the solution for this is to use `track by` like this: `ng-repeat="x in y track by $index | someFilter"`

Comment: yessss it's working now :D thank you everybody :D